# Need help hiding an element based on the time now

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide a div element if the time now is greater then the time specified in the ID attribute. (The time in the ID attribute is a just a php mktime function)

I have wrote the following code below but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks!

```
<div name='test' id='1408702800'>Test</div>

<script>
    $("div[name='test']").function({
    var $time_now =  $.now();
    var $time =  $("#time")
        if($time_now > $time){
            $("div[name='test']").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: $("#time") won't select anything, since there is no element with the "time" id.

Comment: Your id has a UNIX timestamp in seconds while `$.now()` returns a timestamp in milliseconds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First thing, you want to `each` over matching elements and pass it a function that should be executed for each matching element.  Then, grab the timestamp; parse the ID to an integer and make your comparison; then hide only the element you are iterating.

```
var time_now =  $.now();
$("div[name='test']").each(function () {
    if(time_now < parseInt(this.id, 10)){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: ahhh okay. Gotchya! I have another question... Why did you pass the number 10 in the second param of the parseInt function ??

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, your DIV id has a UNIX timestamp in seconds while `$.now()` returns a timestamp in milliseconds.

Loop through your elements using `$.each()` and use `$(this)` to identify the current element.

```
$("div[name='test']").each(function() {

    // Get UNIX timestamp and multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds
    var timestamp = parseInt($(this)[0].id * 1000);

    if ($.now() > timestamp) {

        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ohh okay. I gotchya. Thanks a lot dude!

Answer (score -2):

You should use `document.querySelector(...).getAttribute('id')` (in Javascript **Vanilla**)

At line

`var $time = ...`

you're using an *id* which doesn't exist. :-)